# pdf-reader gem on Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-reader

I'm trying to use the pdf-reader gem
(https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) on my app (RoR with Mongoid).
Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've put the gem in the Gemfile (and have done 'bundle install'). Here's my feedback:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::PDF
```

view-file

```
<% PDF::Reader.new("somefile.pdf")%>
```

I've tried to include the library in the model, but it doesn't work.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ::PDF::Reader
```

I get this error

```
uninitialized constant PDF
```

Do you know how to use the pdf-reader library on Mongoid?
I am looking forward to your answers. THX!

Comment: have you restart the server ?

Comment: I've restarted the server and it works thx!
But now pdf-reader can't open my files:

    `input must be an IO-like object or a filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need restart the server. After all gem add on your Gemfile, you need restart server to have this gem require in your application.